# Does OpenGL allocate on glBegin/glEnd?

Tags: opengl, rendering, memory

You can enclose arbitrary amount of vertices within glBegin/glEnd statements. Does OpenGL limit the number of vertices you create or it allocates memory for more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL implementations aren't assumed to have unlimited memory, but the specification imposes no specific restrictions on this. That is, you can't ask how many vertices you can send. Instead, if you trip some limit, you'll get a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error and rendering will fail.

But in 2023... you're *really* should not care. If you're using old compatibility APIs from 1992, then you probably aren't going to be sending enough vertices to trip any limits from any card that was made after the year 2000. So this is basically sophistry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this complication is needed as I'm writing software renderer in GL style and thinking of possible ways to go with allocations.

Comment: @MaximMogulev: Please don't write a software renderer in the style of a 3-decades-old graphics API. Make the user give you sequences of vertex data as arrays. That will make your consuming code way faster and will eliminate the question, since they are in control of how much memory is allocated.

Comment: Why not? I think old OpenGL versions are more convenient rather than new ones. I like that logical flow of the code you write using this API.

Comment: @MaximMogulev: "Convenient" for what purpose? Convenient for throwing simple stuff onto the screen? Sure. Convenient for serious graphics development work? No. It involves a lot of allocations, but because of the structure of the API, the side doing the allocating *cannot know* how much memory to allocate, while the side requesting the allocation knows exactly how much vertex data they're going to send. If you want to do it, you can, but "convenience" has a price.

Comment: Everything is understandable. I already have a rasterizer for more serious purposes. The thing is in the old style look. Anyways, most of the performance bumps into rasterization stage. I don't experiment with high-poly models. Returning to the question, OpenGL does allocate (no matter how much memory, just the fact of allocation itself), so thank you again for the answer!

Comment: @MaximMogulev No, it's really not convenient for anything or anyone. Not for you developing the API nor for anyone using it, be it even for simple test cases like a cube or a triangle. What does anyone who ever wants to render something have? Yes, a list of vertices at least. And that's what you want to render. *Noone* wants to use Begin/End, neither did anyone 30 years ago. I got an array of vertices, render me an array of vertices. It really makes *everyone*'s life easier. The only reason to do it like GL did 30 years ago is nostalgia. If that's your reason, okay, but "convenience" isn't one

Comment: @ChristianRau: The modern API demands to use buffer objects. Going this way, you indeed reduce draw calls, speed up transfering to GPU and so on. But the old OpenGL provides you instant drawing on calls (as the opposite to fewer calls), instant matrix transformations. If you want to change vertices of an object, you doesn't need to update the whole VBO data, change sub data or do memory mapping (especially this one). Also, if earlier the OpenGL was good as a tool for students, for example, to visualize, experiment, now the specification grew up to DirectX code size to render a triangle.

Comment: @MaximMogulev: "*The modern API demands to use buffer objects.*" But he didn't say anything about buffer objects; he said "arrays". Users should be able to allocate arrays for vertex data and pass them into your software renderer. That's the point: not making a function call for each attribute of a vertex. If they want to change some data, they can just change it in their array. Note that you could do this even in GL 1.1.

Comment: @ChristianRau: But again my inspiration goes from the old style. I like how Processing API made as well. I really want but still can't understand why people prefer doing VBO, EBO, VAO, not having default built-in shader without necessarily writing your own one, not having ability to access built-in shader uniforms and attributes (e.g. glModelViewMatrix, glNormal, gl_Vertex). Why writing only one function to render a cube has lost it's meaning. Actually, my personal favourite API version is 2.1 because it combines both from lower and higher version. Maybe I'll get it all that some day.

Comment: @MaximMogulev: "*I really want but still can't understand why people prefer doing...*" Because all of that stuff is 1) extremely *slow*, 2) requires way too much effort for anything semi-complex, and 3) has limited flexibility. This stuff is useful for new developers *at best,* and even then, I would argue that learning to use buffer objects, shaders, and the like is way better in the long-run than using a child-like API that you will eventually have to ditch if you want to do something vaguely real anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Maybe you're right, yes. Just don't like the monster OpenGL turned into and I hope you agree. So much to wrap, not less to code as new versions being added. But maybe if a wrapper can be done correctly and thought out architecturally, writing code could be easier. Alright, thanks, was interesting to know, will take into account.

Comment: First of all, noone says you have to implement VBOs or anything like that. That's the beauty of a software renderer, just take an array from the user and render that, why emulate GL at all? Implementing Begin/End is a *ton* more hassle, for something that is then clunky to use. And second, I actually do think modern GL is easier and simpler and definitely less code because you only need to actually care about what you use. Simple shaders are basically one-liners with almost no uniforms. But that's beside the point of Begin/End just not making sense for an API that processes a bunch of things.